# Jquery ajax inserting and editing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dropdown

In the function below I have two post request. One to insert values in the database (submit.php) and one to edit existing values in the database based on the businessid (edit.php). However, the script only executes the first part. That is, when "keuze" is select and when clicked on submit, the script nicely inserts into the database. But when something else than "keuze" is chosen and submit is clicked, the script does not edit the records in the database. What can I do to fix this?

```
 submitformfunction: function(){

     $(document).on('submit', '#form', function(){

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var target = $('#busselect option:selected').val();
        var businessid = $('#busselect').children(":selected").attr("id");

        if(target == 'keuze'){

            $.ajax({

              type : 'POST',
              url  : 'submit.php',
              data : data,
              success :  function(data)
                   {
                        alert('Company added');
                   },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            });

        }
        else
        {

            $.ajax({

              type : 'POST',
              url  : 'edit.php',
              data : businessid+data,
              success :  function(data)
                   {
                        alert('Company modified');
                   },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
            });
        }

    });

},
```

submit.php:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "brandveiligheid");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if($_POST )
{

     $naam = addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['uitgevoerd_door_naam']));


     $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO form (uitgevoerd_door_naam) 
     VALUES ('$naam')");

}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

edit.php:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "brandveiligheid");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
     printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
     exit();
}

if($_POST )
{

    $naam = addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['uitgevoerd_door_naam']));


    $mysqli->query("UPDATE form SET uitgevoerd_door_naam='$naam' WHERE id='$_POST[business_id]'");

}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Comment: You've said "does not update".  Does the `edit.php` file even trigger? Have you used the Browser's developer "Network" tab to troubleshoot?  does the AJAX call go out?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attaacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and your edit ajax call fails, because you're passing in `test+businessid`. `test` doesn't seem to exist in your code, and would produce a number/string that PHP won't recognize as a `key=value` form submission, leaving $_POST blank.

Comment: FYI, nice job formatting your code - it looks pretty good! You MIGHT consider three things: double-line-feeds just create open space, so remove the double line feeds - make your `if() {` format consistent - in some places it's on the same line, in some places the `{` is on a line by itself - and lastly, don't use `?>` at the end of your PHP files.  It's now considered best practice to omit those at the end of the php file.

Comment: Just to confirm, have you tried `alert(target);` before if loop? when you select other than `'keuze'` what happens?

Comment: Dear Shrikant, yes I tried that and it yields correct values. Also, @cale_b tnx for mentioned the network tab. The ajax call does go out to edit.php.

Comment: What you see in the browser's developer tools? Is there is any error on `edit.php`?

Comment: Yes there is, I also changed data: test+businessid to data: data+businessid. But it still does not work.

Comment: Just `echo $_POST[business_id];` in your `edit.php` and check in the developer tools, the value is passing or not?

Comment: I echoed it in my edit.php. The only thing alert(data) echoes is the serialised form data that I send

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is issue in query, as '$_POST[business_id]' will be assumed as varchar while datatype of id must be int in database. Try below;

```
"UPDATE form SET uitgevoerd_door_naam='$naam' WHERE id=addslashes(htmlentities($_POST[business_id]))"
```

Also always keep your query secure ;).

Comment: Thx for remarking the addslashes and htmlentities :). However, I tried your solution and I can still not  edit.

Comment: addslashes(htmlentites(...)) is completely inappropriate escaping for this. You should be using prepared statements, but the quicker fix is: `"UPDATE form SET uitgevoerd_door_naam='$naam' WHERE id='" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['business_id']) . "'"`
Alternatively, if `id` is an int column, use `intval` instead of `$mysqli->real_escape_string`.

Answer (score -1):

Do few steps and let me know what you get,
1. in edit.php

```
if($_POST )
{

    $naam = addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['uitgevoerd_door_naam']));

echo $query = "UPDATE form SET uitgevoerd_door_naam='$naam' WHERE id='$_POST[business_id]'";

    $mysqli->query($query);

}
```

2. And in js:
   else
       {

   ```
       $.ajax({

         type : 'POST',
         url  : 'edit.php',
         data : test+businessid,
         success :  function(test)
              {
                   alert(test);
                   alert('Company modified');
              },
           error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
               console.log( errorThrown );
           }
       });
   }
   ```

And let me know what you get in alert.

Comment: Maybe a very stupid question, but what do I need to do to see the output of an echo in an alert?